# OpenGL ES: Drawing small objects

Tags: ios, opengl-es

To best illustrate the issue I'm having, I created a short screen grab. Watch it here: http://cl.ly/1o3p3x2e2J1a1d3d2N1Q

Basically, the stars on the screen, as they're animated across the screen from right to left, are dimming and brightening on their own. I'm not intending on this happening. When you zoom in, the issue disappears.

My hunch is that this has to do with the size of the objects being drawn and the pixel boundaries. Is this correct? What is the best way to go about fixing this issue?

Thanks!

**---Edit---**
Here's how I'm loading the texture: http://pastebin.com/RDc8x7Te
And, here's how I'm setting up OpenGL ES: http://pastebin.com/SpvAqPqA

Comment: I once had such an issue and it just happened to be on the simulator. On the device, it looked just fine. Did you try it on the device?

Comment: @Ravi Indeed. It does happen on my device as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use nearest and linear for scaling textures, which are both not very accurate. You might want to use linear for both, or build mipmaps. Also in case you use an orthogonal view, try aligning your geometry on pixels.

Comment: Thanks, you got me pointed in the right direction. I was using mipmaps and the issue was that I was drawing the object much smaller than the texture I had for it. I fixed my texture and all is well.